# Sine Fourier series and smooth function.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I was reading through my text on PDEs and came across a theorem (or perhaps Lemma) that states:

"For any smooth function $g_1(y)$ with $g_1(0) = g_1(h) = 0$, it  can be expressed
as a Fourier sine series, where y is between $0$ and $h$".

Why is this so?

Edit: to add context

[image: Initial conditions]

[image]

Comment: Is your question about why you can do a Fourier series or why you can simply get away with doing a Fourier *sine* series? The former isn't really appropriate here since it's too broad a question, but if you mean to ask the latter, the way you can think about it is that $g_1$ has a smooth odd extension to the interval $[-h,h]$.

Answer (score 1):

This is from  Fourier series theory (I guess you should remember it)

1. Every smooth function can be expressed as its Fourier series on in interval say on $(-h, h)$. Remember that Fourier series has only sine terms if function $f$ is odd and it has only cosine terms if function $f$ is even.
2. But on half interval $(0,h)$ we can express the any smooth function using only sines (or cosines). For this we redefine function $f$ as odd function $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for $x\in(-h,0)$.

Comment: I have added some context in the OP

Comment: @user And what is the question now?